# In drupal 9 i have try to install Civicrm. But it asking "CiviCRM: Database: Database does not support creation of triggers" how to fix this error?

Tags: webform-civicrm, civicrm.settings.php, drupal-9

i am using Drupal 9, Cent os, php 8, Mysql 8. i am try to install the civicrm it's asking "CiviCRM: Database: Database does not support creation of triggers" how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask your hosting provider to give the mysql user account the TRIGGER privilege: See https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/#mysql-permissions

Comment: this worked thank you